# What is the maximum temperature gradient between two points?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, thermoelectricity

What is the maximum temperature gradient between two points?

If the environment material affect the solution, you can assume that the environment is vacuum.

For example, can we change the temperature from 1000 celsius degree to 100 or 0 celsius degree in an environment?

Please put the reference for your solution.

Comment: Points have no temperature, it is a feature of manybody systems. Please consider 
editing and adding an example to your question.

Comment: Hello @Mauricio, Sorry, that was exactly the same question ,which my professor gave to me? Probably it considers putting two different objects with different temperature adjacent to each other.

Comment: It is still unclear for me. The example you added seems like you are talking about points in time? And the idea that you are giving now is that there are two objects which are in contact? Why refer to the vacuum?

Answer (score 2):

Either you have misunderstood your professor or this is pure brain gymnastics. Let's assume it is the latter. Then to make a temperature gradient you must have at least two objects which can be ascribed temperature. The objects must be integrate within themselves to be called "objects". This latter requirement puts an upper limit on the possible temperature. In case of normal matter such temperature would be on the order of $k_B T\approx 10eV$, that is about ten thousand degrees K. Then you need to have some distance between them. The closest distance between two objects such that they can still be considered separate is limited from below by the typical diameter of the atoms (or conversely the tunneling length of the constituent electrons). This is about $a_{Bohr}\approx 0.05nm$. So your highest possible gradient with normal matter would be about $|\nabla T|_{max}\approx 10^{14}K/m$.

If you want to go crazier and consider nuclear matter take Hagedorn temperature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagedorn_temperature) and divide it by nucleon radius.

Comment: 10,000 K is in correct ballpark; wiki says highest melting point of ordinary stuff at normal pressure is around 4300 K.

Comment: Place 2 materials in contact with,each other. Since the interfacial thermal.resisrance is not null, the temperature gradient is infinite at the,interface.